# Vikings( they'd had)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

It's from the Vikings

"I think a wife was not supposed to nag her husband until THEY'D HAD time to grow tired of each other?"

Why did he use  past perfect here, it should have been only one "had", right??

Comment: No. "Wrong". :)  The past perfect is used **in narrative** to set context and background to the "main" event. The past perfect indicates an action that has ceased in the past but which relates in some way to the main action/state - here, the main action/state is "nag her husband."

Comment: Could you tell me what difference it'd make with a single "had"?

Comment: It would imply that there was a recognised and set time for this nagging, whereas the past perfect does not imply this but rather sees it as an option or condition.

Comment: Using the past perfect or past tense both imply the same meaning in this case, I think.If I used single had then there would be a chronological sequence of action (not supposed to nag to a future event of "until")  but as he used past perfect, it also implies same meaning but we sense the "logical" occurrence of events (as she nagged after "it had happened" ). Do I make sense xD?

Comment: "Until they had time to..." suggests to me that they were waiting until they had sufficient free time to get some task done. Obviously what is meant here is "until sufficient time had elapsed for them to grow tired" - the 'having time' was in the past.

Comment: I can see why past perfect would make more sense but I can't see a world where one 'had' and this context is absolutely 'wrong'  as Greybeard straight-out stated. A couple would expect the magic of their relationship to end after a certain period into the future, right? It is not impossible for this to take place .

Comment: Proximity of the actions decide whether it should be had, or had had. The wife's nagging her husband happens long after the couple were tired of each other. Thus the distant past should be the way it is written above. At least that is what one can make out.

Answer (score -1):

In a comment, Greybeard wrote:

> No. "Wrong". :)  The past perfect is used **in narrative** to set context and background to the "main" event. The past perfect indicates an action that has ceased in the past but which relates in some way to the main action/state - here, the main action/state is "nag her husband."